# RuntimeError: Too many open files when I use pytorch dataloader. (Not opening any files)

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to build and train a neural network using more low level pytorch.
I have the following simple toy code that defines and trains a 6-layer fully connected neural network. The dataset is from a simple sinusoidal function.

```py
# initialise network weights
W1 = torch.randn((1, 30),  requires_grad=True)
W2 = torch.randn((30, 30), requires_grad=True)
W3 = torch.randn((30, 30), requires_grad=True)
W4 = torch.randn((30, 30), requires_grad=True)
W5 = torch.randn((30, 30),  requires_grad=True)
W6 = torch.randn((30, 1),  requires_grad=True)

B1 = torch.randn((30), requires_grad=True)
B2 = torch.randn((30), requires_grad=True)
B3 = torch.randn((30), requires_grad=True)
B4 = torch.randn((30), requires_grad=True)
B5 = torch.randn((30),  requires_grad=True)
B6 = torch.randn((1),  requires_grad=True)


def Neural_net(x, W1, W2, W3, W4, W5 , W6, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6):
    # calculate hidden and output layers
    h1     =  torch.tanh((x  @ W1) + B1)
    h2     =  torch.tanh((h1 @ W2) + B2)
    h3     =  torch.tanh((h2 @ W3) + B3)
    h4     =  torch.tanh((h3 @ W4) + B4)
    h5     =  torch.tanh((h4 @ W5) + B5)
    output =  (h5 @ W6) + B6
    return output

# generating dataset
features = torch.linspace(1,20,50)
features = features.view(len(features),1)
labels   = torch.sin(0.5*features) 

# Creating Dataloader
data_size     = np.shape(features)[0]  
data_set      = torch.FloatTensor(features)          
labels        = torch.FloatTensor(labels)        

dataset = TensorDataset(data_set, labels)
num_batches  =  10
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=data_size//num_batches,
                                         shuffle=True, num_workers=2, drop_last=False)


# training

num_epochs =  10000
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
h  = 0.01/num_batches

for epoch in range(num_epochs):  

    for i, data in enumerate(dataloader):
        x = data[0]
        y = data[1]

        dL1 = 0
        dL2 = 0
        dL3 = 0
        dL4 = 0
        dL5 = 0
        dL6 = 0

        dLb1 = 0
        dLb2 = 0
        dLb3 = 0
        dLb4 = 0
        dLb5 = 0
        dLb6 = 0

        # forward
        outputs = Neural_net(x, W1, W2, W3, W4, W5,W6, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6)
        loss = criterion(outputs, y)
            
        # backward
        dL1 = torch.autograd.grad(loss,W1,create_graph=True)[0]
        dL2 = torch.autograd.grad(loss,W2,create_graph=True)[0]
        dL3 = torch.autograd.grad(loss,W3,create_graph=True)[0]
        dL4 = torch.autograd.grad(loss,W4,create_graph=True)[0]
        dL5 = torch.autograd.grad(loss,W5,create_graph=True)[0]
        dL6 = torch.autograd.grad(loss,W6,create_graph=True)[0]
        
        dLb1 = torch.autograd.grad(loss,B1,create_graph=True)[0]
        dLb2 = torch.autograd.grad(loss,B2,create_graph=True)[0]
        dLb3 = torch.autograd.grad(loss,B3,create_graph=True)[0]   
        dLb4 = torch.autograd.grad(loss,B4,create_graph=True)[0]   
        dLb5 = torch.autograd.grad(loss,B5,create_graph=True)[0]   
        dLb6 = torch.autograd.grad(loss,B6,create_graph=True)[0]   
        

        # optimise
        W1 = W1 - h * dL1
        W2 = W2 - h * dL2
        W3 = W3 - h * dL3
        W4 = W4 - h * dL4
        W5 = W5 - h * dL5
        W6 = W6 - h * dL6
#         
        B1 = B1 - h * dLb1
        B2 = B2 - h * dLb2
        B3 = B3 - h * dLb3
        B4 = B4 - h * dLb4
        B5 = B5 - h * dLb5
        B6 = B6 - h * dLb6
        
    if epoch%10 == 0:
        print('epoch = ',epoch,'loss = ', loss)
```

The problem is, that while the code seems to work at first, training the neural network for a number of epochs, the code stops with the following Runtime error after some time:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [24], in <cell line: 5>()
      3 h  = 0.01/num_batches
      5 for epoch in range(num_epochs):  # loop over the dataset multiple times
----> 7     for i, data in enumerate(dataloader):#, 0):
      8         x = data[0]
      9         y = data[1]

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:517, in _BaseDataLoaderIter.__next__(self)
    515 if self._sampler_iter is None:
    516     self._reset()
--> 517 data = self._next_data()
    518 self._num_yielded += 1
    519 if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \
    520         self._IterableDataset_len_called is not None and \
    521         self._num_yielded > self._IterableDataset_len_called:

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:1182, in _MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter._next_data(self)
   1179     return self._process_data(data)
   1181 assert not self._shutdown and self._tasks_outstanding > 0
-> 1182 idx, data = self._get_data()
   1183 self._tasks_outstanding -= 1
   1184 if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable:
   1185     # Check for _IterableDatasetStopIteration

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:1148, in _MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter._get_data(self)
   1144     # In this case, `self._data_queue` is a `queue.Queue`,. But we don't
   1145     # need to call `.task_done()` because we don't use `.join()`.
   1146 else:
   1147     while True:
-> 1148         success, data = self._try_get_data()
   1149         if success:
   1150             return data

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:1013, in _MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter._try_get_data(self, timeout)
   1011 except OSError as e:
   1012     if e.errno == errno.EMFILE:
-> 1013         raise RuntimeError(
   1014             "Too many open files. Communication with the"
   1015             " workers is no longer possible. Please increase the"
   1016             " limit using `ulimit -n` in the shell or change the"
   1017             " sharing strategy by calling"
   1018             " `torch.multiprocessing.set_sharing_strategy('file_system')`"
   1019             " at the beginning of your code") from None
   1020 raise

RuntimeError: Too many open files. Communication with the workers is no longer possible. Please increase the limit using `ulimit -n` in the shell or change the sharing strategy by calling `torch.multiprocessing.set_sharing_strategy('file_system')` at the beginning of your code
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide the definition of `TensorDataset` class?

Comment: Hi @TheExile ,  I used: from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset

Comment: What is the output of ulimit -n ?

Comment: Hi @Dr.Snoopy , the output is 1024. The same network can be trained fine if I use a pytorch optimiser and define the same architecture using e.g. a class that inherits from nn.Module.